# Access sinatra settings from js

Tags: javascript, sinatra

I'm currently searching for a way to access some settings of my sinatra app from javascript,
is there a simple way to do that?

for the moment i've just tried to assign settings.my_cool_setting to a variable in javascipt but it don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, and I can't think of a reason why would you need server side settings on a client side, but you would pass it to javascript same way you would pass anything else, by either serving it as json through ajax request:

```
require 'json'
get '/settings' do
    s = {my_cool_setting: 'cool'}
    s.to_json
end
```

or serving it as a javascript file that you include in your page

```
require 'json'
get '/settings.js' do
    s = {my_cool_setting: 'cool'}
    "var settings = #{s.to_json};"
end
```

or whatever other way you would push data from server to client.